# Error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" in Armstrong Number program in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a real beginner with PHP, just had my first lesson. We have to create a program that prints Armstrong numbers (up to 10000).

The output should look like this.

```
0 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 0^1 = 0
[…]
8 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 8^1 = 8
9 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 9^1 = 9
153 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153
370 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3 = 370
371 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371
407 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3 = 407
1634 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1634
8208 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4 = 8208
9474 ist eine Armstrong-Zahl: 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4 = 9474
```

That's what I came up with so far. It was working before but now it shows this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\UE\HUE01\bsp-b\index.php on line 14

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: lisap
 * Date: 08.03.2018
 * Time: 18:49
 */

$number = 0;

while ($number>=0) {
    $digits = str_split($number);
    $count = count($digits);
    $result = array_sum(array_map('pow', $digits, array_fill(0, $count, $count)));

    if (($number == $result)) {
        echo $number, ' ist eine Armstrong Zahl: ';
        if ($number < 10) {
            echo $digits[0].'^1 = '.$number.'<br/>';
        }
        if (($number > 9) && ($number < 100)) {
            echo $digits[0].'^1'.$digits[1].'^2 = '.$number.'<br/>';
        }
        if (($number > 99) && ($number < 1000)) {
            echo $digits[0].'^1'.$digits[1].'^2'.$digits[2].'^3 = '.$number.'<br/>';
        }
        if (($number > 999) && ($number < 10000)) {
            echo $digits[0].'^1'.$digits[1].'^2'.$digits[2].'^3'.$digits[3].'^4 = '.$number.'<br/>';
        }
        $number++;
    }
}

?>
```

The output look something like this right now.

```
0 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 0^1 = 0
1 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 1^1 = 1
2 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 2^1 = 2
3 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 3^1 = 3
4 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 4^1 = 4
5 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 5^1 = 5
6 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 6^1 = 6
7 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 7^1 = 7
8 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 8^1 = 8
9 ist eine Armstrong Zahl: 9^1 = 9

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\UE\HUE01\bsp-b\index.php on line 14
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what `echo $digits[1];` is trying to access? *Hint*: It is an array of 1 length and you are trying to access the second element.

Comment: Interesting that you're getting anything at all, since it shouldn't even hit the loop. `var_dump($digits);`, and you'll see there's only 1 value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you are using the function `str_split` in the wrong way. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

> If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length.

So, replace

```
$digits = str_split($number,10000);
```

With

```
$digits = str_split($number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments/improvements to make to your code.

1. If you use a `for` loop instead of a `while`, you won't need to check for the upper bound yourself.
2. You can use `**` instead of `pow()` which should simplify your `array_sum()` and `array_map()` line.
3. You could use a basic loop to iterate over each digit, rather than handling each case.
4. `str_split()` doesn't need 2 arguments. You can see the function definition on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).
5. Most importantly, you are not `break`ing out of your `while` loop. This will run forever unless you cancel it. This is why my first point is useful.

Some notes on the following example:

1. On line #2 I am casting `$i` to a `string`. This isn't needed as PHP will do it for you. I was just highlighting that an `int` is being converted to a `string` here.
2. The inverse is happening on line #10. `$n` (which is a string returning from `str_split()`) is being implicitly cast as an `int`.

---

See my example:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $split = str_split((string) $i);
    $total = 0;
    $str = '';
    foreach ($split as $k => $n) {
        if ($k !== 0) {
            $str .= ' + ';
        }
        $str .= "{$n}^3";
        $total += $n ** 3;
    }
    $str .= " = {$total}";
    echo "{$str}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
php armstrong.php
1^3 = 1
...
1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153
...
3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3 = 370
...
3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371
...
4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3 = 407
...
```

You can increase the max execution time of the script with [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: do you have a solution how I will get more output (0-9 and from 1000 - 10000)?

Comment: To include numbers that aren't Armstrong numbers? You can remove the last if statement. I'll update the answer.

Comment: If this answer helps, you should remember to vote and accept answer.